# Workaround for CSS vw bug with desktop scaling in IE9

Tags: css, windows-7, internet-explorer-9, scale

I'm using the CSS `vw` property in a page to give a `<div>` 50% page width (this is just an example). Here is the code:

```css
*
{
 /* Zero padding/margin by default. */
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 /* Fix CSS. */
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

#left
{
 left: 0;
 width: 50vw; /* SHOULD BE 50% WIDTH! */
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 top: 50px;
 bottom: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
</head>
<body>
 <center>|</center>
 <div id="left"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a red box that should take up the left half of the page (halfway indicated by the `|`). It works fine normally, but when you set desktop scaling on Windows to 125% (default is 100%) it doesn't work in IE9. With desktop scaling at 125% it looks correct in Firefox:

[image: firefox]

And incorrect in IE9:

[image: ie9]

My question is: does anyone know of a workaround for this?

This is the setting that causes the problem (Windows 7):

[image: stupid_windows]

Answer (score 0):

**See edit below.**

I came up with a vaguely clean solution. Fortunately Windows only supports a few values of desktop scaling: 100%, 125%, 150% in Windows 7, and 200% in Windows 8 (or 8.1? I don't remember). And even more fortunately, it reports the correct relative-to-96 DPI via CSS media queries. All in all it means you can do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
 
 <style>
 *
 {
  /* Zero padding/margin by default. */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Fix CSS. */
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 #left
 {
  left: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
 }
 </style>
<!--[if IE]>
 <style>
 /* Windows 125% scale. */
 @media (resolution: 120dpi) { 
  #left {
   width: 40vw; /* 50 / 1.25 */
  }
 }

 /* Windows 150% scale. */
 @media (resolution: 144dpi) { 
  #left {
   width: 33.333vw; /* 50 / 1.5 */
  }
 }

 /* Windows 200% scale. */
 @media (resolution: 192dpi) { 
  #left {
   width: 25vw; /* 50 / 2 */
  }
 }
 </style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
 <center>|</center>
 <div id="left"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Quite hacky, but not too bad, and it works perfectly. It does mean you have to calculate multiples of all your `vw` and `vh` values though.

## Edit

As noted in the comments, it works fine *unless* you zoom with the mouse wheel as well as have desktop scaling on. Frankly, IE9 is fucked. I ended up going with this javascript which doesn't work perfectly still:

```
<script>
function endsWith(str, suffix) {
    return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
}
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; ++i) {
    var factor = screen.systemXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI;

    var rules = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules;
    for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; ++j) {
        var style = rules[j].style;
        for (var k = 0; k < style.length; ++k) {
            // This is weird I know.

            // Change style names from 'max-height' to 'maxHeight'.
            styleName = style[k].replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(str, letter) {
                return letter.toUpperCase();
            });

            if (style[styleName] != undefined) {
                // Replace vw and vh's.
                newVal = style[styleName].replace(/([.0-9]+)(v[wh])/g, function(str, num, unit) {
                    return (parseFloat(num) / factor) + unit;
                });
                if (style[styleName] != newVal) {
                    style[styleName] = newVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually this worked for my computer, but not on someone else's. Possibly her DPI was not set to 96 originally (although I thought all CSS was 96 DPI). I will have to investigate.

Comment: Ah I have found out why this doesn't work. If you zoom (ctrl+mousewheel), the DPI changes. Seriously IE.